# Responsive front-end web layer

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, mobile-website

I am planning to build a web application that is accessible through different devices, PCs with large displays, Tablets and mobile phones (IOS, Android).

What is the best practice in doing this? Should I build two front-end layers, one for PCs and the other one for mobile devices with touch screens? (I suppose both will be responsive too)

Or should I make a single responsive front-end that can adapt to all famous screen sizes?

What are the advantages and disadvantages of both methodologies? Suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Consider using Responsive [HTML5 Boilerplace](http://www.initializr.com/).

HTML5 boilerplate is the a great way to start any web site.  The responsive design works well for any platform.  [Try out the responsive design](http://www.initializr.com/try)

Answer (score 1):

You can also take a look at [15 Responsive CSS Frameworks Worth Considering](http://speckyboy.com/2011/11/17/15-responsive-css-frameworks-worth-considering/) for a selection of frameworks.